# Custom Icons in bottom navigation view , android studio XML doesnt work

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

Custom icons i will attach them above doesn't work as the bottom navigation view icons. When i put them without setting the appiconTint they are just becoming Pink filled squares? When i add appiconTint and set it to transparent or make a custom tint at drawable made out of the same images, they just become black/white filled squares. if i type out: appIcontTint=" " they work! but the XML doesnt allow me to leave it empty. Once i add any value to that things are becoming colored squares instead of my icon. I am attaching a pictures so you can have a better understanding. [Colored squares with appIconTint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZkW8.png)
[works without appIconTint value but gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUbpR.png) There are the icons, they are in png format: [png icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojjjb.png) I specifically want to use these icons if its possible. Thanks for any help! oh here is my code:

```
        <!-- BottomNavigationView -->
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconTint=""
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconSize="60dp"
            android:background="#2d3135"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_unpressed"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_unpressed"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/reels_unpressed"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_heart"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_unpressed"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_unpressed"
        android:title=""/>

    </menu>
```

I have tried changing different files/values in appIconTint . Leaving it colored/transparent/ creating a seperated drawable file that includes selector with unpressed/pressed states of those icons. I have selector made in 1 file for all of them and also 5 different selectors for each seperetly. Tried spliting icons into 2. For instance that white profile seperated and the black bg of it seperated and putting it on top on bottom nav. It didn't work either. I tried disabling iconTint by java. Any help would be appreiciated! Thanks